# How to pass a Smart Pointer in a method without deleting it

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I have a program that checks me some tokens, the first time it checks the one with the least HP, the other times it takes one randomly. I thought about transforming this code using the strategy pattern. The code works, but there is a problem: the tokens are cleared

*Token*

```
class Token{
private:
    string name;
    int hp;
public:
    Token(string N, int H){
        name=N;
        hp=H;
    }
    string GetName(){
        return name;
    }
    int GetHp(){
        return hp;
    }
}
```

*Strategy.h*

```
    #ifndef MAIN_CPP_STRATEGY_H
    #define MAIN_CPP_STRATEGY_H
    
    #include "Token.h"
    
    class EnemyStrategy{
    protected:
        std::unique_ptr<Token> token[3];
    public:
        virtual int Start() = 0;
    };
    
    class FirstCase : public EnemyStrategy{
    public:
        FirstCase(std::unique_ptr<Token> pieces[3]){
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                token[i] = std::move(pieces[i]);
                std::cout<<token[i]->GetName()<<"\n";
            }
        }
        ~FirstAttack(){}
        int Start() override{
            int min=100;
            int attacked;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (token[i]->GetHp() <= min){
                    min = token[i]->GetHp();
                    attacked = i;
                }
            }
            return attacked;
        }
    };
    
    class SecondCase: public EnemyStrategy{
    public:
        int pawns;
        SecondCase(std::unique_ptr<Token> pieces[3]){
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                token[i] = std::move(pieces[i]);
        }
        ~SecondCase(){}
    
        int Start() override {
            int i = rand() % 3;
            return i;
        }
    };
    
    //Controller
    class Controller{
        EnemyStrategy* strategy;
    public:
        Controller(EnemyStrategy* tm): strategy(tm){
    
        }
        ~Controller(){
    
        }
        int WhoToAttack(){
            return strategy->Start();
        }
    };
    #endif //MAIN_CPP_STRATEGY_H
```

*MainCode*

```
#include "Strategy.h"
#include "Token.h"

int main(){
    unique_ptr<Token> token[3];
    token[0] = make_unique<Token>("Knight", 20);
    token[1] = make_unique<Token>("Mage", 5);
    token[2] = make_unique<Token>("Fighter", 10);

    Controller* controller;
    EnemyStrategy* strategy;
    if (control == 0) {
         strategy = new FirstAttack(std::move(token));
    } else {
         strategy = new WarStrategy(std::move(token));
    }
    controller = new Controller(strategy);
    attacked = controller->WhoToAttack();
    cout<< "\n the token:" <<attacked; //WORKS
    cout<<token[attacked]->GetName(); //DON'T WORKS
    delete strategy;
    delete controller;
}
```

My fear is that pointers go out of scope once called in the function, and for this the Strategy pattern works, but the program crashes at: `token[attacked]->GetName()`

I don't know how to do it, ideas?

At first I left the unique_ptr smart pointers but then I tried to replace them with shared_ptr, but nothing has changed

Comment: Deleted C tag as it is not related to C. Do not use both

Comment: Please make a [mre]. These unrelated snippets are just confusing (me).

Comment: If you don't want `EnemyStrategy` to own your `Token`s, don't have it store `unique_ptr`s to them.  Use raw pointers as observers.  Also you should avoid using raw pointers to own objects like you're doing with `strategy` and `constroller`.  Those should probably be a `unique_ptr<Strategy>` and a `Controller` (no pointer needed), respectively.

Comment: @0___________: Do not promulgate "Do not use both" as a universal rule.  There are plenty of cases which should combine both.  You are correct in removing the `c` tag from this particular question, but that's because it doesn't apply here, not because of any universal rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt it is as C and C++ are different languages. For example `(++x)--` (assuming C++11+)

Comment: @0___________: And questions about calling either language from the other one should use both tags.  The rule is not universal.  Tags should be removed from questions that don't involve the tagged language, not "because some other tag was used and they can't go together".

Comment: You should use `std::array` to get value semantics when passing arrays to functions. The "array decays to pointer" semantic is just to confusing. It also looks like premature optimization. A `Token` is a tiny structure that doesn't really benefit from move semantic. If you must you probably gain more by making your code const correct and/or using references and avoid even the moves. PS: the strings will use short string optimization so they don't move. Why aren't the strings const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
if (control == 0) {
    strategy = new FirstAttack(std::move(token));
} else {
    strategy = new WarStrategy(std::move(token));
}
```

`std::move` doesn't do anything, because arrays are passed by pointer.

The move occurs in the strategy constructor for each element:

```
FirstCase(std::unique_ptr<Token> pieces[3]){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        token[i] = std::move(pieces[i]);
        std::cout<<token[i]->GetName()<<"\n";
    }
}
```

After that, you can't use the tokens in `main`.

This also happens when using `shared_ptr`, but `shared_ptr` is copyable and you are not forced to use `move`. To use `shared_ptr`s, remove the move from the strategy constructor:

```
FirstCase(std::shared_ptr<Token> pieces[3]){
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        token[i] = pieces[i];
        std::cout<<token[i]->GetName()<<"\n";
    }
}
```